# Eclipse can't find Driver.class from postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar file nor AbstractJdbc4Connection class

Tags: postgresql, java, pgadmin-3

I am using the jar file in my configuration path after following the example from [postgresql/jdbc tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqljavatutorial/). But after I added the jar file and configured it for my reference library when I run it I am getting an error that says it can't find the source attachment for that jar file despite my retrieving that jar file from the jdbc postgres website. I have tried a couple of different configuration methods, but it the jar file and its classes have mostly already been added with the exception of a couple classes like Driver.class. Should I use a different version or is it a configuration issue? I don't believe its something in my code yet because no code error other than not finding the driver class would cause that.

I am connecting to pgadminIII to update some rows.

Comment: Show the *exact text* of the error message. The "source attachment" shouldn't be necessary for runtime, it's only needed if you're debugging and stepping into/through PgJDBC.

Comment: oh ok, I see. In that case its not a big issue then because I only receive the error when I am debugging which I thought was necessary for runtime despite when I run it normally the error doesn't come up. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Is this not more of a SO question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message excerpt you mentioned it sounds like Eclipse is only complaining about the source attachment.

The source attachment - an archive or directory containing the source code from which a given binary jar was crated - is only required for debugging, when you're stepping into/through PgJDBC code. It is not necessary to run programs that use PgJDBC.